# ¿Cómo hago referencia a una variable que he creado con un for en python?

Tags: python-3.x

estoy en python y estoy intentando crear un programa que me pregunte cuantos lados de una figura geométrica tienes para luego calcular el perímetro y eso se hace sumando todos los lados.

La cuestión es que quiero que me pregunte por el tamaño de los lados con un for y eso lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
lados = int(input("Dime cuantos lados tiene la figura geométrica: "))
for i in range(lados):
    globals()['var{}'.format(i)] = input("Dime el valor de un lado: ")
```

Al ejecutar ese código lo que estoy haciendo es guardar en la variable "var" el valor de ese lado.
La variable "var" va aumentando de número después de cada for, por ejemplo "var1, var2, var3".

Lo siguiente que quiero hacer es sumar las variables que me ha creado, pero como eso depende del número de lados, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Porqué no crear una variable en la que almacenes la suma de los lados?

```
lados = int(input("Dime cuantos lados tiene la figura geométrica: "))
perimetro = 0
for i in range(lados):
    lado = input("Dime el valor de un lado: ")
    perimetro = perimetro + lado
```

No he probado el código pero ten cuidado con el tipo de variable que recoges en la variable **lado** para la suma del perímetro

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer luego las variables de `global()` creadas, tomando la cantidad de lados que antes has introducido. En este caso, yo por ejemplo haría lo siguiente: Recorrer luego las variables que he añadido a `global()` y ir sumando su valor en otra variable independiente que he llamado `suma`, la cual luego imprimo. Por ejemplo:

```
lados = int(input("Dime cuantos lados tiene la figura geométrica: "))
for i in range(lados):
    globals()['var{}'.format(i)] = input("Dime el valor de un lado: ")
suma = 0
for i in range(lados):
    suma += int(globals()['var{}'.format(i)])
    
print(str(suma))
```

Aunque sinceramente, si no te importa perder el valor de la longitud de cada lado, pues solo quieres la suma total, puedes acortar el bucle solo añadiendo cada valor introducido por el teclado a la variable suma. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
lados = int(input("Dime cuantos lados tiene la figura geométrica: "))
suma = 0
for i in range(lados):
    suma += int(input("Dime el valor de un lado: "))
    
print(str(suma))
```

Las dos formas funcionan, pues las he probado, así que escoge la que mejor te venga.

Comment: Ohhh, comprendo, muchas gracias !!!

Comment: Me alegro @Iithlyion!! Si te ha parecido que la respuesta es correcta, puedes marcar el check verde que se encuentra a la izquierda, pues sirve de ayuda para otros que tengan tu misma pregunta. ;D